# Will formatting a USB 3.1 flash drive using a USB 3.0 port on Windows 10 switch the drive to USB 3.0?

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, formatting

Now this may be a bit of a stupid question, but if you were to format a USB flash drive using Windows 10, and the port is USB 3.0, will the flash drive switch to USB 3.0?

If the answer is yes, if I were to install USB 3.1 drivers beforehand, would the flash drive stay USB 3.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it won't, formatting doesn't mean that USB 3.1 become 3.0 or 2.0.
It just deletes all information on the USB drive, it will stay USB 3.1 no matter what you do.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will be fine. Formatting just means that it will erase the information on the USB drive. The difference between USB 3.1, 3.0 and 2.0 is just the speed of transferring files from the drive or off the drive.